# Cross Domain Session and Cookies in JS-PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies, cross-domain

On a 3rd party website (e.g. xyz.com) I am loading a Javascript (e.g. from mysite.com/lib.js)

When I make the first XHR call to mysite.com/1.php, I setup a session and also store a cookie.

After the 1st XHR has succeeded, I make a 2nd XHR call to mysite.com/2.php

However 2.php can neither see the session, nor the cookie. Both $_SESSION and $_COOKIE are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: 1.php and 2.php both have: if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}

Comment: I imagine you set up CORS header to allow the xhr request from xyz.com to mysite.com. Can you confirm that ?

Comment: As in above. 1.php and 2.php each explicitly have the above code. Should I have done something else?

Comment: Actually, the debug console of the browser should indicate issues if there are any with the cross domain request. I think you may need na `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET` in your server's response to the OPTIONS request if you have issues and a `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header too, maybe (check the doc)